# Is there a way to return an Object from stream after Filter? Getting ClassCastException

Tags: java, java-stream, classcastexception

I want to return an object from a list via a stream.

```
return (planlinevaluesEntityList != null ? (PlanlinevaluesEntity) planlinevaluesEntityList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getMandantKagId()
                    .equals(Long.valueOf(mkId))) : null);
```

But I get a ClassCastException:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to class de.pares.int_plan.entity.PlanlinevaluesEntity...

I also tried to use "findFirst()"..

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `Stream` operation required a `Terminal` operation to return anything else than a `Stream`. In your case, you have multiple choices: `findAny()` or `findFirst()`. Both return an `Optional<T>` that you can unwrap using `orElse(null)`.

If you need an explicit cast, just like in your question, you can use `filter` and `map` like hereunder

```java
if (planlinevaluesEntityList == null) {
    return null;
}
return planlinevaluesEntityList.stream()
                               .filter(p -> p.getMandantKagId()
                                             .equals(Long.valueOf(mkId))
                               )
                               .filter(PlanlinevaluesEntity.class::isInstance)
                               .map(PlanlinevaluesEntity.class::cast)
                               .findFirst()
                               .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (planlinevaluesEntityList != null ? planlinevaluesEntityList.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getMandantKagId()
                        .equals(Long.valueOf(mkId))).findFirst() : null);
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.